# Cookie is not being deleted

Tags: session, cakephp, cookies

I've seen other questions of this problem, but nothing solved my problem:

I'm using cakephp, the code for setting/unsetting cookies is on AppController -> beforeFilter() to make sure it works correctly (is going to be the first portion of code to be executed before the actual page)

Let's see... for the login:

```
                if($data['check'] == 'on')
                    $_SESSION['cookieActivation'] = 0;

                $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'info', 'action' => 'index'));
```

For beforeFilter()

```
session_start();

        //Esto es para eliminar la cookie, si la hay, y también sacar la sesión (deslogear)
        if (isset($_SESSION['cookieRemoval']))
        {
            if (isset($_COOKIE['user'])) //está la cookie, en primer lugar?
            {
                unset($_COOKIE['user']);
                setcookie('user','',1);
            }

            unset($_SESSION['cookieRemoval']);
        }


        //esto se setea si el tipo puso recordar contraseña en el login de dreyfus, se hace acá porque 
        //es el lugar correcto para setear la cookie, si se intenta hacer después, no funciona

        if(isset($_SESSION['cookieActivation']))
            if($_SESSION['cookieActivation'] == 0) //cero significa que quiere setear cookie porque todavía no lo hizo...
                {
                    //si quiere que recuerden su login, hacemos una cookie
                    //va a expirar en 30 días... 3600 es una hora....
                    $_SESSION['cookieActivation'] = 1;
                    setcookie('user','pass',time()+(3600*30*24));
                }
```

for logout

```
 $_SESSION['cookieRemoval'] = 1; //avisa a appcontroller que quiere borrar la cookie de sesión...
            $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'info', 'action' => 'login'));
```

Ok, that's a lot of code, let me explain it a bit:

If you do login, it sets a session variable to state that you want to set a cookie.
Then in it goes to beforefilter, it checks that you actually want to set a cookie, and it sets it for 30 days.

when you do logout, a session variable is created to specify that you want to remove the cookie, then it goes to beforefilter and then it detects that session variable and removes the cookie.

It works well, it redirects to a login page and with a printr the results are that I no longer have the cookie set... BUT, if I do F5 or close the browser and open the page again... the cookie is still there.

Any... tips here?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by being extra specific when setting the cookie, like this:

Create cookie:

```
setcookie('user','pass',time()+(3600*30*24), '/', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
```

Delete cookie:

```
setcookie('user','',1, '/', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
```

I basically added those last two fields...